# Does Poisson disk sampling technique of MeshLab require a triangulated mesh?

Tags: meshlab

I have an (oriented) point cloud for some underlying surface that I want to downsample without having to construct a triangulated mesh of the surface. If I load the point cloud into MeshLab and try to use the Filters/Sampling/Poisson-disk Sampling option, will MeshLab first construct a triangulated surface of the point cloud before performing the sampling, or can it do the sampling without needing a mesh?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify a point cloud using a Poisson-Disk subsampling strategy you do not need a triangulated surface, just use the filter "Point Cloud Simplification" (for which I have just committed a better description explaining that the simplification is done using poisson disk subsampling)